# VBAにて、MSProjectの特定範囲内のアウトラインを出力したい

Tags: vba

VBAにて、MSProjectの特定のアウトラインのものだけを出力したいと考えています。

例えば、アウトライン「1.1.1.1」を取り出したいとき

```
If outline Like "[1.]" Then
```

だと、「.」が含まれてしまうもの全てが出力されてしまって悩んでいます。

何か、良い方法はないものでしょうか？

なお、取り出すのは1つや2つではないので文字列の完全一致での出力はしたくないと思っています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [OutlineLevel プロパティ (Project)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task.outlinelevel) と [OutlineNumber プロパティ (Project)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task.outlinenumber) の関係が、この質問 [Unable to Create Correct Hierarchy of Tasks while Exporting to MS Project using VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23336295/9014308) のように階層になっているらしいので、それを基に範囲を絞り込むとか考えられませんか？

Comment: kunifさん> ありがとうございます。こちら確認し、絞り込めないか考えてみます。